# PostgreSQL count number of times substring occurs in text

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm writing a PostgreSQL function to count the number of times a particular text substring occurs in another piece of text. For example, calling count('foobarbaz', 'ba') should return 2.

I understand that to test whether the substring occurs, I use a condition similar to the below:

```
    WHERE 'foobarbaz' like '%ba%'
```

However, I need it to return 2 for the number of times 'ba' occurs. How can I proceed?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Check out my answer for an updated method of doing this http://stackoverflow.com/a/42708237/124486

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would highly suggest checking out this answer I posted to [*"How do you count the occurrences of an anchored string using PostgreSQL?"*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/166763/2639). The chosen answer was shown to be massively slower than an adapted version of `regexp_replace()`. The overhead of creating the rows, and the running the aggregate is just simply too high.

The fastest way to do this is as follows...

```
SELECT
  (length(str) - length(replace(str, replacestr, '')) )::int
  / length(replacestr)
FROM ( VALUES
  ('foobarbaz', 'ba')
) AS t(str, replacestr);
```

Here we

1. Take the length of the string, `L1`
2. Subtract from `L1` the length of the string with all of the replacements removed `L2` to get `L3` the difference in string length.
3. Divide `L3` by the length of the replacement to get the *occurrences*

For comparison that's about **five times faster** than the method of using `regexp_matches()` which looks like this.

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM ( VALUES
  ('foobarbaz', 'ba')
) AS t(str, replacestr)
CROSS JOIN LATERAL regexp_matches(str, replacestr, 'g');
```

Answer (score 10):

How about use a regular expression:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM regexp_matches('foobarbaz', 'ba', 'g');
```

The `'g'` flag repeats multiple matches on a string (not just the first).

Comment: Check out [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42708237/124486) for an update to this question and a comparison of both this method and an optimal way of doing this. Or, my answer to another question on DBA.SE, ["How do you count the occurrences of an anchored string using PostgreSQL?"](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/166763/2639).

Answer (score 1):

There is a

```
str_count( src,  occurence )
```

function based on

```
SELECT (length( str ) - length(replace( str, occurrence, '' ))) / length( occurence )
```

and a

```
str_countm( src, regexp )
```

based on the *@MikeT*-mentioned

```
SELECT count(*) FROM regexp_matches( str, regexp, 'g')
```

available here: [postgres-utils](https://bitbucket.org/andi1234/postgres-utils)

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
SELECT array_length (string_to_array ('1524215121518546516323203210856879', '1'), 1) - 1

--RESULT: 7
```