# I want to count the number of occurences of a value in a string

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, postgresql-8.4, unnest

Given a column namely `a` which is a result of `array_to_string(array(some_column))`, how do I count an occurrence of a value from it?

Say I have `'1,2,3,3,4,5,6,3'` as a value of a column.
How do I get the number of occurrences for the value `'3'`?

Comment: if `a` is the result of `array_to_string(array(some_column))` why not just `count(CASE WHEN some_column=3 THEN 1 END)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL count number of times substring occurs in text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25757194/postgresql-count-number-of-times-substring-occurs-in-text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it myself. Thank you for all the ideas!

```
SELECT count(something)
FROM unnest(
        string_to_array(
            '1,2,3,3,4,5,6,3'
        , ',')
    ) something
WHERE something = '3'
```

Comment: This should also be the accepted answer, since it's superior.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to use **unnest**.

Try this:

```
select idTable, (select sum(case x when '3' then 1 else 0 end) 
from unnest(a) as dt(x)) as counts 
from yourTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

why not just create a for loop() and increment a variable i within an if/else statement for whenever a value == 3

```
for(var i =0; i<intArray.length;i++){
     if(int[i] = 3){
     var j += 1;
```

}
}

something like that, hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: This answer seems misplaced. The procedural approach is no match for a set-based solution in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

[Based on my *"How do you count the occurrences of an anchored string using PostgreSQL?"*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/166763/2639)

The fastest way to count occurrences in a sub-string is this.

```
SELECT length(data) - length(replace(data, '3', ''))
  / length('3')
FROM foo;
```

If you're creating the string with `array_to_string`, it makes sense to `unnest`, but it won't be faster. Moreover, I would love to see the full query.

```
count(CASE WHEN some_column=3 THEN 1 END)
```

sounds the fastest, or if you upgrade to a new version of PostgreSQL..

```
count(*) FILTER (WHEN some_column=3)
```